# Bootstrap navbar not working. Why?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

```
        <html>
<head>
    <title>Advertisements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Advertisements</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>advertisements">Advertisements</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>users">Users</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

     <div class="row">
        <?php require($view); ?>
     </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

It should create a navbar with design but only plan text shows up. I have both of the stylesheets and it is working in another project. I copied all the requested files, the links are working as well. I can visit other pages But there none of my stylesheets are working (Just like in this case.) Why is this ?

Comment: any error in console??

Comment: where are `ROOT_URL` and `$view` defined as?

Comment: if none of the stylesheets are working make sure the path in the href attribute is correct  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">

Comment: have you included the  `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`....must required?

Comment: As I mentioned, no errors and I can reach all my requested pages 
The ROOT_URL is defined in the config.php

Comment: Sure looks like a link path issue.... try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css">`

Comment: and you included the config where exactly? and are you sure this is a php question then? your question's unclear. Seems to me you're probably seeing code rather than parsed php.

Comment: this isn't a php question then. I removed the tag in an edit. If there is relevance, you can add it back in.

Comment: the two stylesheets are in the css folder in the assets folder which is a folder in my project. 
I did like this in another project and it worked. Exactly like this. 
Only 2 buttons deleted

Comment: you can press ctrl+u to see you homepage code and then click on bootstrap link which you'll added if it is added right code will display other wise it'll be redirect to nothing.

Comment: from the code you provided and if you say the style paths are correct then all should be good, maybe provide a link to the project if is live or on a dev server somewhere

Comment: Sorry but this is the most I could share. 
Idk what is the problem but I have to hand it in soon. If there won't  be answers, I will make my style and leave this shit out

Comment: What version of Bootstrap (4) are you using?

Comment: 4.0.0 is my version

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you add `bootstrap.js` file in your header
and put this code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

for more details check this [Bootstrap Components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Comment: This is tagged for **Bootstrap 4** so you should link to the right docs.